# WAR - Gradle multi-module app - TypeNotPresentException

Tags: java, gradle, war, ktor

I have an application with a Gradle module structure similar to this:

- `app - applies war`
- `common/utilities`
- `common/auth`
  etc.

The `app` module applies the WAR plugin. When deployed to a remote server, this exception comes back:

```
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type [SomeClass] not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:90)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:777)
    at org.kodein.di.TypeReference.<init>(types.kt:272)
```

Clearly, classes from depended-on modules are not being brought into the WAR somehow (which is exposed via Kodein service locator usage) - this is not intuitive since that wouldn't be the case if it was packaged into a JAR or AAR.

Anyone know why this may be happening and how I can change my Gradle configuration to fix it?

---

Edit: if I expand the WAR, I see external Maven dependencies are brought into `lib` as JARs along with non-app modules. All of the compiled Kotlin classes from the `app` module are in `classes`. I guess it's not working because the main app JAR is not bringing in the module JARs, for some reason.

Comment: The jar files from the subprojects (like `utilities`) should be in the `lib` folder - not the `classes` folder. If they are missing, how are you declaring dependencies on them?

Comment: @BjørnVester ah right - yes, thanks - so the module JARs do appear to be there, confirmed by expanding and looking for the "missing" classes. 

There is a dependency graph, so a mix of "api" and "implementation". I tried switching them all out for the old "compile" synax, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I noticed MANIFEST.MK only contains a manifest version, there are no module dependencies defined there. I wonder if that's related? Strange that it doesn't just work as-is with the Gretty and WAR plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simpler than expected. My module structure has modules like this:

- :app
- :common:auth:public
- :common:auth:impl
- :common:data:public
- :common:data:impl

The `public` and `impl` submodules go into the WAR as `public.jar` and `impl.jar`, it doesn't handle duplicates at all. So some modules were being left out.

I couldn't figure out how to change the outputted JAR names so I ended up changing the names like this:

- :app
- :common:auth:data-public
- :common:auth:data-impl
- :common:data:data-public
- :common:data:data-impl